# Jupyter interact ipywidgets: several widgets for one argument

Tags: python, ipython, ipywidgets, python-interactive

Is it possible to link several widgets to one argument?
I have these three boolean widgets:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, fixed

w1 = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description='Widget 1')
w2 = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description='Widget 2')
w3 = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description='Widget 3')
```

The function I'm trying to call with interact has an argument that is a list of three bools. 
For example:

```
def test(x, data):
   if all(data):
      # do something
```

Now I tried using interact by e.g. `interact(test, x=fixed(3), data=[w1, w2, w3]);` but it gives the error

> 'Checkbox' object is not iterable

Is there any way that I can link those three widgets to the single argument `data`? I have to keep this argument as a list of bools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, fixed

w1 = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description='Widget 1')
w2 = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description='Widget 2')
w3 = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description='Widget 3')

def test(**kwargs):
    x = kwargs.pop('val')
    if all(kwargs.values()):
        print(x)
      # do something

interact(test, val = fixed(3), w1=w1, w2=w2, w3=w3);
```